# How to add menu button without action bar?

Tags: android, android-menu

I'd like to add a menu button to the right top corner of my app and without action bar, like it is in Google Fit app on the screenshot below.
Can anyone help me?

[image: menu button without action bar]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can simply use `PopupMenu`, for example add the following to a button when clicked:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

Kotlin

```kotlin
fun showPopup(v : View){
   val popup = PopupMenu(this, v)
   val inflater: MenuInflater = popup.menuInflater
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.menu)
   popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
      when(menuItem.itemId){
         R.id.action1-> {
             
         }
         R.id.action2-> {

         }
      }
      true
   }
   popup.show()
}
```

For more info, read `Creating a Popup Menu` :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Where should i call this method ?

Comment: Item click listener can be added like this:

popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menuItem1:
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });

Comment: Use `popup.gravity = Gravity.END` just before inflating it if you want it to be on the right side of the screen (Showed up on the left for me by default)

Comment: @Quinn Seems like it is not supported prior to API level 23. However, you can pass gravity as a constructor argument: `PopupMenu(this, v, Gravity.End)`, which is supported.

Answer (score 20):

Add a toolbar the layout and make it transparent.  That is the best solution to adding menu items to a layout while giving the appearance there is no actionbar/toolbar.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The rest of your code here -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Theme**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Example of inflating the menu, setting title, menu click listener.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Toolbar");
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_refresh) {

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Don't set the Toolbar as the action bar.  The theme just removes it totally.

Comment: it has white background, it's not transparent!

Answer (score 9):

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow_holo_dark"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_overflow_button"
    android:onClick="showPopup" />
```

Add above lines in xml file where you want to show this menu.

```
public void showMenu(View v) {

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    // This activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup.inflate(R.menu.actions);
    popup.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.archive:
            archive(item);
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            delete(item);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

For more details go through:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: `onMenuItemClick` doesn't exist what are you talking about?

Comment: `onMenuItemClick` completly working till now. [see this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can add a menu without action bar. But, there are 2 approaches I can think off.

1. Create and Action bar of the same color as that of the background so that it does not show, next add the menus.
2. Just add a button on the top right corner of the screen and put the drop down in the layout.

Or Use a Pop up menu as suggested by @M-Y