# Android: How to create options menu outside action/tool bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need help on how I would make an options menu outside of toolbar. The one with the dropdown like the options menu in chrome or messaging, not the contextual which pops up like an alert/progress dialog.

I am planning to use it beside a textview, not on a toolbar. I get the idea of having to create an xml for the menu, but what do I use on the layout and how do I inflate it?

Comment: If you are going to create it outside the actionbar/toolbar, why do you even what it as menu? You could simply create it as a spinner.

Comment: But spinners work like an edit text with dropdown right? I was thinking of creating it exactly like the options menu typically found on the toolbar which only has that icon with three dots, and shows the dropdown items when you click it, but in a different position (outside the toolbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to add menu button without action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417223/how-to-add-menu-button-without-action-bar)

those are two pretty acceptable solutions, doubt there is any other workaround...or just use a spinner

Comment: Resolved it with popupmenu. Didnt knew about it before. Thanks!