# How to hide ActionBar but still show Navigation menu icon on top left

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I try to hide ActionBar in Navigation View by using `getSupportActionBar().hide()` but it makes menu icon on top left dissapear too, like this :
[image]

I want it show like this :

[image]

Could someone give me some advice ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add menu button without action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417223/how-to-add-menu-button-without-action-bar)

Comment: Yes, but i want to call the navigation menu,however that question only need to call popup menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just done it,for anyone need it, just create an ImageView and handle click event with this:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't because the icon is part of `ActionBar`. You can create `ImageView` (or `Button`, ...) and place it at the top-left position and handle click event or use transparent `ToolBar`

Comment: Thank you, can you show me how to call out the navigation view menu with onClick event on an 'ImageView'

Answer (score 0):

Add a **ImageButton** and fix it's position to top left corner . And handle the click event of the button using **OnClickListner** ... Simple ...