# How do I get my verticial ellipsis menu to show on my android app without a toolbar in android studio?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, menu, android-toolbar

I want to have only an ellipsis menu in the top right corner of my app which is currently located on my toolbar. I have tried removing my toolbar from my app but when I do my ellipsis menu disappears too. I want the ellipsis menu to show all the time even when scrolling and I don't want it to be on a transparent toolbar as that might affect other interactive features in my app. How do I make it so that this works?

My menu is tagged in my activity_main.xml file at the top:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
app:menu="@menu/my_menu">
```

I have tried to remove the toolbar in my themes.xml file but the ellipsis menu also disappears. Whats the best and easiest way of solving this problem?

Comment: Did you try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417223/how-to-add-menu-button-without-action-bar

Comment: Yes I already did but I am not looking for a pop-menu, and neither a transparent toolbar. I need a solution specific for my problem.

Comment: That menu needs a parent to be inflated on, how do you think some other solutions can work? It's not like that menu will just stay up in the 'air', no?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can or cannot stay up in mid air, I'm trying to find the best solution for my specific problem, that's why I've asked this question otherwise if I had the answer I wouldn't have asked this question.